# Gearbox in 10GBASE-R Ethernet protocol

Tags: ethernet, transceiver, gigabit, 10gbase

In 10GBASE-R specification, Gearbox is defined to take care the data width adaptation between PCS & PMA. For example, after the 64b66b encoding, the PCS data width will become 66bits.

The gearbox will adapt the 66-bit datawidth to whatever data width that PMA is support.

May i know if we can have a PMA with serializer factor of 66. Does that mean Gearbox is not necassary or not needed in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, if the width is the same, you won't need a gearbox. But most high performance serializers are going to be a power of two, and 66 is not a power of two, so you're pretty much guaranteed to need a gearbox.

Comment: Yes, i understand that serializer factor of 66 does'nt make sense. Just want to verify my understanding.

However, FPGA vendor like altera (Intel) does support 20 & 40 serializer factor. I think mainly is due to 8b10b reason.

Comment: That's a good point, but 5 is a relatively reasonable non power of two factor to handle. Serializers supporting 8b10b usually support 5*2^n widths. 66, on the other hand, is 2*3*11, which needs two different oddball factors, which is not so nice to implement.

Comment: To tell the "serializer factor" of xilinx transceiver (UG578 for example), is it to check the freq ratio betw two clocks to PISO block as shown in Figure 3-30 of UG578? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I randomly saw this. So even IEEE maybe says something about direct connection..
But I am really new to this so correct me :D

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/319658)

Comment: It is the IEEE standard 802.3 for PCR -R . It shows an indication that Gearboxes are not always used. The interface from PCS to PMA should be at least able to use the XSBI format.